# Hide inner label in pieChart Charts pod swift

Tags: ios, swift, charts, cocoapods, pie-chart

I know there is the way to off (or hide) this inner labels in pieChart elements (circled in the image)! [pieChart inner label image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4eCT.png)
I try (all pieChart methods responsible for this i found in my opinion):

```
pieChart.drawEntryLabelsEnabled = false
pieChart.entryLabelColor = UIColor.clear
pieChart.drawCenterTextEnabled = false
```

But still labels are visible...

Comment: Are you trying to hide value labels? If so, you need to set drawValuesEnabled = false for the dataset.

Comment: It works! You helped me! What can i do for you?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're trying to hide "value" label. And for that, you need to set *drawValuesEnabled = false* for your dataset.

I think "value label" is being mixed up with "entry label" and "center text", so check out the image for your better understanding.

```
    // label inside the circle
    pieChart.centerText = "center text"
    
    // dataset for the pie chart
    let data = PieChartDataSet(entries: [
        PieChartDataEntry(value: 100, label: "entry label")
    ])
    
    // hides entry label
    pieChart.drawEntryLabelsEnabled = false
    
    // set clear color for entry label = hides entry label
    pieChart.entryLabelColor = .clear
    
    // hides center text
    pieChart.drawCenterTextEnabled = false

    // hides value label
    data.drawValuesEnabled = false

    pieChart.data = PieChartData(dataSet: data)
```

[image: chart]